# How to standardize strings between rows in a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following pandas DataFrame in Python3.x:

```
import pandas as pd

dict1 = {
    'ID':['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth'], 
    'pattern':['AAABCDEE', 'ABBBBD', 'CCCDE', 'AA', 'ABCDE']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(dict1)

>>> df
       ID   pattern
0   first  AAABCDEE
1  second    ABBBBD
2   third     CCCDE
3  fourth        AA
4   fifth     ABCDE
```

There are two columns, `ID` and `pattern`. The string in `pattern` with the longest length is in the first row, `len('AAABCDEE')`, which is length 8.

My goal is to standardize the strings such that these are the same length, with the trailing spaces as `?`.

Here is what the output should look like:

```
>>> df
       ID   pattern
0   first  AAABCDEE
1  second  ABBBBD?? 
2   third  CCCDE???
3  fourth  AA??????
4   fifth  ABCDE???
```

If I was able to make the trailing spaces `NaN`, then I could try something like:

```
df = df.applymap(lambda x: int(x) if pd.notnull(x) else str("?"))
```

But I'm not sure how one would efficiently (1) find the longest string in `pattern` and (2) then add `NaN` add the end of the strings up to this length? This may be a convoluted approach...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`Series.str.ljust`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.ljust.html#pandas.Series.str.ljust) for this, after acquiring the max string length in the column.

```
df.pattern.str.ljust(df.pattern.str.len().max(), '?')

# 0    AAABCDEE
# 1    ABBBBD??
# 2    CCCDE???
# 3    AA??????
# 4    ABCDE???
# Name: pattern, dtype: object
```

In the source for Pandas `0.22.0` [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/0.22.x/pandas/core/strings.py#L960) it can be seen that `ljust` is entirely equivalent to `pad` with `side='right'`, so pick whichever you find more clear.

Comment: I never new about `Series.str.ljust()`. Thanks for this!

Comment: @ShanZhengYang No worries. There are a whole bunch, see [String handling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#string-handling) in the docs.

Answer (score 8):

You can using `str.pad`

```
df.pattern.str.pad(width=df.pattern.str.len().max(),side='right',fillchar='?')
Out[1154]: 
0    AAABCDEE
1    ABBBBD??
2    CCCDE???
3    AA??????
4    ABCDE???
Name: pattern, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 3):

### Python 3.6 f-string

```
n = df.pattern.str.len().max()
df.assign(pattern=[f'{i:?<{n}s}' for i in df.pattern])

       ID   pattern
0   first  AAABCDEE
1  second  ABBBBD??
2   third  CCCDE???
3  fourth  AA??????
4   fifth  ABCDE???
```

---

Comment: can you please explain what is f-string doing here..