# Add 0 at last if length is not matching in python

Tags: python, pandas

If A of string length is not matching 8 add zero of last . if its matching and its remains same.

```
A           Out_put
6122        61220000
6700        67000000
654322      65432200
634523      63452300
62169822    62169822
67543444    67543444
```

Comment: You need a [`ljust`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.ljust.html), ``df.A.astype(str).str.ljust(8,'0')``

Comment: Here is a dupe, https://stackoverflow.com/a/49908757/4985099

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to standardize strings between rows in a pandas DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49908710/how-to-standardize-strings-between-rows-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: You may think about accepting an answer to reward those how helped you, or at least comment to explain what's missing ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Series.str.ljust`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.ljust.html)

> *Filling right side of strings in the Series/Index with an additional character.*

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [6122, 6700, 654322, 634523, 62169822, 67543444]})
df['Padd'] = df['A'].astype(str).str.ljust(8, '0')
print(df)
#            A      Padd
#  0      6122  61220000
#  1      6700  67000000
#  2    654322  65432200
#  3    634523  63452300
#  4  62169822  62169822
#  5  67543444  67543444
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try out apply() method and built the logic on your own to do the above task. The logic is as follows:

```
def fill(val):
    return str(val)+'0'*(8-len(str(val)))

df['A']  = df['A'].apply(fill)
```

Comment: Do your if on len(str(val)) not on the val itself. Also you don't need the if? if it's not length 8, you'll multiply by 0

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
df['Out_put'] = df['A'].astype(str).apply(lambda x: x + '00000000').str[0:8]
```

output:

```
    A           Out_put
0   6122        61220000
1   6700        67000000
2   654322      65432200
3   634523      63452300
4   62169822    62169822
5   67543444    67543444
```

Comment: ``ljust`` would be the right way for doing this as shown by @azro.

Answer (score -1):

```
            number=input()

            if(len(number) <= 8):
                number=number + '0'*(8-len(number))
                print(number)
```

Comment: number expects any input from the user, which can be the number strings listed in the question, to give the desired output
A           Out_put
6122        61220000
6700        67000000
654322      65432200
634523      63452300
62169822    62169822
67543444    67543444